# bigquery ML: Running a regression per group and all combined

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a BQ table that includes multiple groups. I'd like to run a regression per group and all combined.

Regression looks like:

```
for group id = 1 -> predicted_metric ~ metric 1 + metric 2
for group id = 2 -> predicted_metric ~ metric 1 + metric 2
for group id = 3 -> predicted_metric ~ metric 1 + metric 2
...
for group id = 40 -> predicted_metric ~ metric 1 + metric 2
```

Is it possible to run this regressions and getting the coefficient estimates in a table?

Answer (score 2):

BQML currently doesn't support specifying different group ids in a single CREATE MODEL statement for regression.

As an alternative, you could try using BQ [procedural language](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/procedural-language) to run multiple(40 in your case) CREATE MODEL statements with WHERE clause(WHERE group id = 1,2,3,...,40) in one query. Similarly, you could run [ML.WEIGHTS](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-ml/docs/reference/standard-sql/bigqueryml-syntax-weights) on the 40 trained models to get the coefficient.