# Bigquery ML for multiple linear regression models on partitions in a table

Tags: machine-learning, google-bigquery, regression, distributed-computing

### Task

I want to perform multiple linear regression on partitions in a table using bigquery ml and preferably implemented using dbt.

### Background

The table contains customer_key, category, week_key and spend. The regression line should be calculated for each partition:  customer_key and category, sorted by week in ascending order. So that each customer, per category obtains a slope coefficient of the trend in spend across the weeks within that partition. Effectively, I would need one regression model per partition and not one for the entire table. The amount of regression models is estimated to be around 100 million. Thus, I wanted to use bigquery to enable parallelization of the workload.
[image]

The end result should be a table containing: customer_key, category, slope for all customers.
[image]

Additionally, I am using dbt to run all my models using bigquery as compute and storage of my data. Therefore, I would like to implement the solution using dbt.

### Research

From chatting with various llms they seem to suggest a combination of procedural statements and for loops across each partition to perform a regression. However, I want to parallelize the computation. From this question [bigquery ML: Running a regression per group and all combined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74100927/bigquery-ml-running-a-regression-per-group-and-all-combined), it seems that "BQML currently doesn't support specifying different group ids in a single CREATE MODEL statement for regression.".

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE partitioned_data AS
SELECT customer_key, category, week_key, spend
FROM your_table
GROUP BY customer_key, category;

DECLARE partition_list ARRAY<STRUCT<customer_key INT64, category INT64>>;
BEGIN
-- Iterate over each partition in the staging table
FOR partition IN (
  SELECT customer_key, category
  FROM partitioned_data
  GROUP BY customer_key, category
 )
 LOOP
   -- Extract data for the current partition
 DECLARE partition_data ARRAY<STRUCT<week_key INT64, spend FLOAT64>>;
 BEGIN
  FOR week_data IN (
    SELECT week_key, spend
    FROM partitioned_data
    WHERE customer_key = partition.customer_key
    AND category = partition.category
  )
  LOOP
    array_append(partition_data, week_data);
  END LOOP;
END

-- Create a model for the current partition
CREATE OR REPLACE MODEL my_model
OPTIONS(
  model_type = 'linear_regression',
  labels = 'spend',
  features = 'week_key'
)
AS
SELECT *
FROM UNNEST(partition_data);
END LOOP;
END;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE final_results AS
SELECT
  s.customer_key,
  s.category,
  m.slope
FROM partitioned_data p
JOIN (
  SELECT
    *,
    slope = MEAN(statistics.mean_slope)
   FROM ML.MODEL_STATS(model.my_model)
   GROUP BY customer_key, store_key, category
  ) m
 ON p.customer_key = m.customer_key
 AND p.category = m.category;
```

However, this suggested solution does not work to run in the bigquery gui and not in dbt.

#### Question

How to accomplish this regression task? Either running above sql-code as a separate script on bigquery or rewriting it to work in dbt.

Comment: I'm no mathematician ... but based on your story ... and your determination that you are looking for the gradient of a line (slope), is there actually a need to use regression at all?  Your data seems to be merely a set of points ... x=week, y=spend.   As such, given a set of these points for a given "partition", you should be able to use arithmetic to calculate the slope ... see  https://www.quora.com/How-is-the-line-of-the-best-fit-calculated-without-a-calculator

Comment: Yes, in the case of just y=kx+m, k can be solved quite easily with SQL However, in higher dimensions it will become a bit more difficult, and hence the interest in using bigquery ml.